# Shopify Checkout extensibility : checkout UI edit default values

Tags: shopify, checkout, shopify-app

I was creating checkout ui extension with help of latest Shopify cli which is part of checkout extensibility update.

I was trying to edit few values such as Total amount and Recurring total amount (which I was used to do with jQuery in previous liquid theme)

but in checkout UI i cant seem to update things like Total amount , like i used to previously

so anyone has anything to input, any suggestions or direction for me to think for

Thanks, help is appreciated

I followed the basic documentation

Comment: No you cannot edit the dom with the new checkout ui. You can only modify your own extension component